# How does error management work in callr package?

Tags: r, error-handling, callr

I'm trying to figure out how to use the error handling in the `callr` package (which creates sub processes for R).

Here is a reprex:

```r
rp <- callr::r_bg(function() stop("You should see this"), error = getOption("callr.error", "error"))
Sys.sleep(2)
rp$get_result()
#> Error: ! in callr subprocess.
#> Caused by error in `(function () …`:
#> ! You should see this
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

What I want to accomplish is to suppress the messages `#> Error: ! in callr subprocess. #> Caused by error in (function () …:` and only show `Error: You should see this`. The background is that this will go into a function and I think it will confuse users to see the callr reference.

It seems that the error argument could be used to accomplish that. The documentation reads:

> error: What to do if the remote process throws an error. See details below.

But I can't find these details and don't know what options might be valid here.

Comment: If `#> Error: ! in callr subprocess.` appears consistently on errors, I wonder if you can just split the string and take what appears after it. It's kinda scrappy, but might be a practical solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not sure if this is worse than leaving it in there :(

Comment: I also see a lot of code for error handling in the github repo, but it seems rather complex.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found this in the documentation of `r_bg`:

> #' @inheritParams r

Which indicates that the answer to my question is in the help file of the function `callr::r`:

> ## Error handling
>
> callr handles errors properly. If the child process
> throws an error, then callr throws an error with the same error
> message in the main process.
>
> The error expert argument may be used to specify a different behavior
> on error. The following values are possible:
>
> - error is the default behavior: throw an error in the main process,
>   with a prefix and the same error message as in the subprocess.
> - stack also throws an error in the main process, but the error is of a
>   special kind, class callr_error, and it contains both the original
>   error object, and the call stack of the child, as written out by
>   utils::dump.frames(). This is now deprecated, because the error thrown
>   for "error" has the same information.
> - debugger is similar to stack, but in addition to returning the
>   complete call stack, it also start up a debugger in the child call
>   stack, via utils::debugger().
>
> The default error behavior can be also set using the callr.error
> option. This is useful to debug code that uses callr.
>
> callr uses parent errors, to keep the stacks of the main process and
> the subprocess(es) in the same error object.

In other words, the message can not be suppressed at the moment (as far as I can see), except with something hacky like this:

```
rp <- callr::r_bg(function() stop("You should see this"), error = "error")
Sys.sleep(2)

res <- tryCatch(rp$get_result(), error = function(e) {
  # e <<- e
  e$message <- "my package"
  print(e)
})
#> <callr_error/rlib_error_3_0/rlib_error/error>
#> Error: 
#> ! my package
#> Caused by error in `(function () …`:
#> ! You should see this
#> ---
#> Subprocess backtrace:
#> 1. base::stop("You should see this")
#> 2. | base::.handleSimpleError(function (e) …
#> 3. global h(simpleError(msg, call))
```